# Not detecting WLAN adapter after re-installing Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers, netbook

I have an Asus EEE 1201N netbook that I just formatted. I am getting all the drivers from [here](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Eee%20PC%201201N&p=20&s=1).

So far all have worked fine except the WLAN drivers. I get a weird error

> Sorry ! We do not support this operation system !!

So I googled around and found out that this netbook uses a Realtek 8191 adapter, which I downloaded and installed drivers for. Still not working:

> No connections are available

This is really frustrating as I can't do anything without WLAN working. If anyone can offer an idea it would be appreciated.

**edit**: I decided to get the drivers for Windows XP instead (from the same link as above). Installation gave the same error, but then Windows 7 offered to try re-install the drivers with the "correct settings" (I assume this is the "compatibility options" that Tom was talking about). Anyway, now it works. Go Asus.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Try to set the compatibility options to the OS the drivers were designed for.

   Please note that between XP and Vista the driver architecture has changed, so it might not work.
2. Obtain the right drivers for your operating system.